# R constrainted all combinations

Tags: r, constraints, combinations

I have some vectors like this

```
V1=[1,2,3,4,5]
V2=[7,8,9,10,11]
V3=[15,16,17,18,19]
V4=[3,4,5,6,7]
```

I would like to get all possible combinations from these vectors that look like this `[V1[i],V2[j],V3[k],v4[z]]` and that sums up to 3+9+17+5. This is a bit different from the duplicate because I would like to get all combinations with one element from each vector and not get all combination from one vector.
For example the following lists are solutions

```
[1,11,17,5] 
[2,8,18,6]
[5,9,15,5] 
......

and many others are.
```

Any ideas on how to implement this in R?

Comment: FWIW the answer to this question is a *subset* of the linked duplicate (i.e., the duplicate is looking for a random sample from this set, not just how to enumerate it).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understood the linked duplicate solution but still can't figure out how to implement it for my problem. I am still a beginner with R. I tried to bind the vectors to a matrix using x<-rbind(x,v1) .... then I use perms <- permutations(nrow(x),nrow(x), x, repeats.allowed=T) but I actually this would generate permutations from only the first row of x. I would rather have permutation with one element from each row.

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe as the dupe target is asking about a single vector. This problem is asking for combinations where each element comes from a different vector such their sum is a particular number.